# how to stop the while loop in only a certian part of the while loop body (python 3)

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, break

```
area_names = ['The Living Room', 'Master Bedroom', 'Guest Bedroom', 'Kitchen', 'Garden', 'Garage', 'Bathroom', 'Diner Area', 'Storage Room', 'Fitness Area', 'Pool', 'Gaming Room', 'Family Bedroom 1', 'Family Bedroom 2', 'Office 1', 'Office 2', 'Basement', 'Hall way', 'Theater Room', 'Basket Ball Court']
area_descriptions = []
graph = [[1, 10, 3, 5], [-1, -1, -1, 0], [-1, -1, 16, -1], [-1, 0, -1, 7], [5, -1, -1, -1], [0, 8, -1, 4], [-1, -1, -1, 18], [3, -1, 13, 17], [-1, -1, 5, -1], [10, -1, -1, -1], [19, 18, 0, 9], [16, -1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, 12, -1], [-1, 7, -1, -1], [17, -1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1, 16], [15, 17, 2, 11], [7, 12, 16, 14], [6, -1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1, 10]]

pygame.display.update()

inventory = [] 
intial_area = 'The Living Room'

while True:  
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit() 
    next_locations = []  
         
    print('You are positioned at',intial_area,'right now')
    print()
    print('the next location(s) you can access are: ')
    print()
    
    location_num = area_names.index(intial_area)

    for node in graph[location_num]:
        
        if node >= 0:
            print("\t", area_names[node])
            next_locations.append(area_names[node])
        elif node < 0:
            print('')
            next_locations.append('')    
    print()
    if intial_area == 'Theater Room':
        take1 = input("there is a controller collictible in this area(type 'take' inorder to collect it) ").lower()
        if take1 == 'take':
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (86, 303, 48, 34))
            inventory.append('PS5 Controller')
        else:
            print('you have to type "take"')          
    elif intial_area == 'Garden':
        take2 = input("there is a flower collictible in this area(type 'take' inorder to collect it) ").lower()
        if take2 == 'take':
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, lime, (591, 513, 33, 32))
            inventory.append('Flower')
        else:
            print('you have to type "take"')
    elif intial_area == 'Gaming Room':
        take3 = input("there is a figurine collictible in this area(type 'take' inorder to collect it) ").lower()
        if take3 == 'take':
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (914, 542, 13, 18))
            inventory.append('Figurine')
        else:
            print('you have to type "take"')

    
    directions = input("Which direction would you like to go? ").lower()
    
    if directions == 'north' or directions == 'west' or directions == 'east' or directions == 'south':
        if directions == 'north':
            next_location = next_locations[0]
        elif directions == 'west':
            next_location = next_locations[1] 
        elif directions == 'east':
            next_location = next_locations[2]
        elif directions == 'south':
            next_location = next_locations[3]
        
        # logic for good answer
        if next_location in area_names:
            intial_area = next_location
        else:
            print("That area does not exist")
    else:
        print('that is not a direction')
        # go next loop

    print()

    show = input('do you want to show inventory? ').lower()

    if show == 'yes':
        print(inventory)
    elif show != 'no' and show != 'yes':
        print('just type either "yes" or "no"')
    elif show == "no":
        continue
```

so in this program i am implementing a map  with 20 areas and the user has to navagate through it via text in the terminal by using directions (i.e. north, west, etc) and also add some collictible in the map that the user can collect only once per game, but the problem here is that i dont know how to stop the loop on certian parts of the while loop inorder to simulate the user taking the collictible permenantly while simulatinously still looping on the others. the part i want the while-loop to ignore when the user types 'take':

```
        if take1 == 'take':
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (86, 303, 48, 34))
            inventory.append('PS5 Controller')
        else:
            print('you have to type "take"')
```

Comment: Can't you simply condition this part with " if 'PS5 Controller' not in inventory: ... " ?

Comment: I still don’t really understand